# Getting error: Shapes not aligned, with statsmodels and simple 2 dimensional linear regression

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm


list21 = [-0.77, -0.625, -0.264, 0.888, 1.8, 2.411, 2.263, 2.23, 1.981, 2.708]
list23 = [-1.203, -1.264, -1.003, -0.388, -0.154, -0.129, -0.282, -0.017, -0.06, 0.275]

X1 = np.asarray(list21)
Y1 = np.asarray(list23)
    
x = X1.reshape(-1, 1)
y = Y1.reshape(-1, 1)

   
model = sm.OLS(x, y)
fit = model.fit()

y_pred = model.predict(x)
```

Error reads as:

```
--> 161     y_pred = model.predict(x)

ValueError: shapes (10,1) and (10,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 499 (dim 0)
```

Been banging my head against the wall for the past half hour please help.

Comment: aside: statsmodels requires the dependent or outcome variable to come first, i.e. `OLS(y, x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning the predict to the wrong variable. Use:

```
model = sm.OLS(x, y)
fit = model.fit()
y_pred = fit.predict(x)
```

Or use

```
model = sm.OLS(x, y).fit()
y_pred = model.predict(x)
```

In either case: assign predict to the variable you used with `fit()`

**EDIT**

To answer your question why the line goes through zero: You are not defining an intercept, which you can do with sm.add_constant. Please refer to this documentation: https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/ols.html

Applied to your code you get:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list21 = [-0.77, -0.625, -0.264, 0.888, 1.8, 2.411, 2.263, 2.23, 1.981, 2.708]
list23 = [-1.203, -1.264, -1.003, -0.388, -0.154, -0.129, -0.282, -0.017, -0.06, 0.275]

x = np.asarray(list21)
y = np.asarray(list23)
X = sm.add_constant(x)
model = sm.OLS(y,X)
results = model.fit()
y_pred = results.predict(X)
plt.scatter(list21,list23)
plt.plot(x,y_pred)
```

Comment: Yep that was it thanks. Do you know why my line is only passing through 0 on the y-axis? even if I change the lists, it always go through zero. Thats really not what should be happening. My other regression line doesn't do that.

Comment: Please check my edit. I reworked your example so you can see how to get a proper regression line using ols. :)